# Como executar uma function no cron job?

Tags: php, laravel, cron

Gostaria de saber como e qual a melhor maneira de efetuar uma cron job, se eu escrevo ela como uma function direto na cron? Gostaria de efetuar ela todo dia as 6h.

```
public function atualizarpontuacao(){
       $palpites = Listadepalpites::all();
       $data = date('Y-m-d');
       $data1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data. ' -3 days'));
         foreach($palpites as $p){
           $palpitea = $p->palpitea;
           $palpiteb = $p->palpiteb;
           $id       =  $p->id;
           $id_c     = $p->id_c;
           $id_u     = $p->id_u;
          $confrontos = Listadejogos::Find($id_c);
           $scorea   = $confrontos->scoretimea;
           $scoreb   =  $confrontos->scoretimeb;
           $pontuacao =3;

           DB::update("update palpite set pontuacao='$pontuacao' where (id='$id' and diadojogo > '$data1') ");

         }
```

Comment: Bom você executa uma função no Cron exatamente como uma função é executada num arquivo no navegador comum...

Então, você tem um arquivo com uma função chamada `getAllUsers($parametros);` então, no fim do arquivo que você setou no Cron, você bota `getAllUsers($parametros)` e é isso...

Boa sorte

Comment: Minha duvida é que uma function sempre é executada com uma chamada. e no script eu tenho que escrever a function ou como?

Comment: Cron para mim é intimamente ligada à linha de comando. Execute na linha de comando seu programa e ele mostrará o mesmo comportamento no cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como você está usando o Laravel, você pode escrever essa sua função dentro do método `protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)` da classe `App\Console\Kernel`.

O exemplo de como ficaria sua função segue abaixo:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule) {
    $schedule->call(function () {

       $palpites = Listadepalpites::all();
       $data = date('Y-m-d');
       $data1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data. ' -3 days'));

       // Código segue...

    })->dailyAt('06:00');
}
```

Para seu código entrar no cronjob, você também precisa colocar a seguinte linha no seu cronjob:

`* * * * * php /caminho-para-o-projeto/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

**EDIT**

Você também pode usar as classes `Command` para agendar os jobs (particularmente, você consegue reaproveitar melhor o seu código dessa forma).
Segue um exemplo:

1. Abra o CMD na pasta do seu projeto e digite `php artisan make:command AtualizaPontuacao`.
2. O Laravel vai gerar um arquivo chamado `AtualizaPontuacao.php` dentro de `app\Console\Commands`. Dentro dela, vai haver um atributo chamado `protected $signature`. Nesse atributo, você vai dizer qual a assinatura do seu comando. Por exemplo: `atualiza:pontuacao`.
3. Dentro do método `public function handle()`, você pode escrever todo o seu código.
4. Para que seu comando funcione, volte para a classe `App\Console\Kernel` e adicione dentro do atributo `protected $commands = [ ... ]` o nome da sua classe Command: `App\Console\Command\AtualizaPontuacao::class`
5. Agora, altere o código que está dentro do método `protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)` para o exemplo abaixo:

   `$schedule->command('atualiza:pontuacao')->dailyAt('06:00');`
6. Pronto! Agora, seu código irá rodar tanto no cronjob como manualmente também, através do comando `php artisan atualiza:pontuacao`.

Para mais configurações de horários e datas do cronjob e commands, acesse a documentação do Laravel:

CronJobs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/scheduling

Artisan Commands: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/artisan#writing-commands